# Use -isystem instead of -I with CMake

Tags: gcc, build, cmake

Is there any way in CMake to force a path specified via include_directories (or perhaps through a different function) to use the -isystem flag instead of the -I flag when building with gcc?

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options for details on -I and -isystem.

Comment: Hi. I'm here from 8 years in the future. The use of isystem by cmake has now , strangely enough, with the addition of include_next, broken a good number of builds, especially cross builds.

Comment: Regarding what @donbright said, consider visiting this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37218953/1233251

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yes you force a path to be a system include by using the optional SYSTEM flag

```
include_directories(SYSTEM path)
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html

Starting with CMake 2.8.12 you can use the new target_include_directories to include system directory includes at the target level, while leveraging the new usage requirement features of cmake:

```
target_include_directories(foo SYSTEM PUBLIC path)
```

Now target foo will use path as a system include, and anything that links to foo will also use path as automatically as a system include. You can control the propagation of these usage requirements by changing the PUBLIC keyword to PRIVATE or INTERFACE.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html

Comment: The command should be `include_directories` without `set_` prepended.

Comment: For me this did not worked on MAC OS 10.8, cmake 2.8.1: until I used a `CMAKE_INCLUDE_SYSTEM_FLAG_CXX="isystem"` just before the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` directive.

Comment: @math have you tried upgrading cmake to a newer version? 2.8.1 is a couple years old.

Comment: On OS X with CMake 3.1 this works with `include_directories`, but not `target_include_directories`, for some reason.

Comment: On OS X with CMake 3.2.2 this doesn't work with `include_directories`, nor with `target_include_directories`, setting `CMAKE_INCLUDE_SYSTEM_FLAG_CXX` doesn't help in either case.

Comment: @zenith Neither can I get it to work on OS X with recent CMake versions (3.x). I opened a question with a minimal example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31722426/1027706

Comment: For me it is not working, but I guess this is because the included directory only contains a header file, i.e. all warnings are propagated to the target's object files? Correct?

Answer (score 13):

As stated already, the correct way to include system paths is:

```
include_directories(SYSTEM path1 path2)
```

However as of CMake 2.8.4 and Makefiles, This is only used for C++ and not C, I looked into it and GNU.cmake does not initialize: `CMAKE_INCLUDE_SYSTEM_FLAG_C`

So you can set this yourself right after calling `project()`.

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
  set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_SYSTEM_FLAG_C "-isystem ")
endif()
```

## Update:

The CMake developers have fixed this in 2.8.5

Comment: Yes, it was fixed in 2.8.5. This is the commit with the fix: http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=33f5a83a5d7aa4c5a021c33a3fa55069da5eeed8

Answer (score -9):

You could try using `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to add additional flags.

Comment: While you can add includes with CMAKE_C/CXX_FLAGS This isnt really useful, CMake has methods to add includes and typically you want to make use of those.

Comment: You should always keep your hands off of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` or `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`. There is `target_compile_options` to add flags.