# QtCreator's code inspector breaks when I use -isystem flag instead of INCLUDEPATH

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I wanted to suppress warning from external libraries which can be done by [marking them as system libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867065/607407). I figured out this is how to do it in `.pro` QtCreator project file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem ../libs/boost159/
```

The problem is that QtCreator relies on the `INCLUDEPATH` setting, expects this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += ../libs/boost159/
```

If I remove it, the QtCreator no longer can find boost libraries:

[image: image description]

I originally wanted to report this as a bug but after some reports I no longer believe the QtCreator developers will ever consider fixing this. Instead, I came here for a workaround.

Because [**qmake has conditional statements**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#scopes-and-conditions) I could make use of something like this:

```
isCompiling {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem ../libs/boost159/
} else {
    INCLUDEPATH += ../libs/boost159/
}
```

So that QtCreator's parsing would not fail but upon compile, `isystem` would be used. Any ideas?

*Exoplicitly:* How can I make a conditional expression that will only trigger/not trigger when QtCreator is parsing the project file?

Comment: Please make the question explicit. So far it looks as if you were documenting your exploration and stopped mid-sentence :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discovered the solution. You need to use `qmake` additional arguments and specify a variable of your choice, then test if it's defined. Since QtCreator doesn't know about these parameters, it won't execute the block intended for compilation:

```
# This variable is set as "CONFIG += compiling"
# The assignment is done in qmake command line argument
compiling {
  # This block takes effect during real compilation
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem ../libs/boost159/ -isystem ../libs/openssl/include
} else {
  # This block is seen by QtCreator and other tools that do not have 'CONFIG compiling' defined
  INCLUDEPATH += ../libs/boost159/ ../libs/openssl/include
}
```

The setting then must be done in project management. Don't forget to set it for both release and debug:

[image: image description]

Comment: Glad I could help. Note that there's one caveat which occurs when C files are included and compiled via C compiler. I assume `QMAKE_CFLAGS` is the correct variable for those but I did not finish my research on that topic.

Comment: Thanks for the caveat - my case is for headers only where libraries are linked (or are header-only libraries).