# How can get g++ to use my own glibc build's headers correctly?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, glibc, include-path

There's a TL;DR at the end if the context is too much!

**Context**

I am trying to update the version of glibc a project uses to 2.23 (I know it's old, that's another issue). In order to do this, I need to swap out the libraries and use the associated interpreter.

I encountered some issues when swapping out the interpreter that looked like an ABI change, so I figured it was probably because the header files had changed somehow and started working on getting those included into the project.

At first I tried using `-I` to include the headers, but got an error (see below). Later I tried setting `--sysroot`, but this quickly felt like the wrong way of doing things since I was essentially reinventing what g++ already did with system headers. I later found another mechanism that looked more promising (see Problem section).

Could this be an [XY issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Absolutely, but either way, the problem I'm seeing seems odd to me.

**Problem**

I looked into whether there was a different mechanism to include headers for system libraries, such as glibc, in gcc and g++. I found the flag `-isystem`:

> ```
>    -isystem dir
>       Search dir for header files, after all directories specified by -I but before the standard system directories.  Mark it as a system directory, so that it gets the same special treatment as is applied to the standard system directories.  If dir begins with "=", then the "="
>       will be replaced by the sysroot prefix; see --sysroot and -isysroot.
> ```

I figured that this was probably wanted and set about intergrating this flag into the build system for the project. The resulting g++ command looks like this (simplified and broken onto multiple lines):

```
> /path/to/gcc-6.3.0/bin/g++
  -c
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
  -Wl,--rpath=/path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/lib
  -isystem /path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/include
  -I.
  -I/project-foo/include
  -I/project-bar/include
  -o example.o 
  example.cpp
```

This leads to the following error, followed by many similar ones:

```
In file included from /usr/include/math.h:71:0,
                 from /path/to/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/cmath:45,
                 from example.cpp:42:
/path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/include/bits/mathcalls.h:63:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 __MATHCALL_VEC (cos,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
```

Looking into this, it appears that this particular `math.h` is incompatible with this version of glibc. The fact it tries to use it surprises me, because the `math.h` file exists in the glibc directory I specified; why didn't it use that? Here's how I verified that file exists:

```
> ls /path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/include/math.h 
/path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/include/math.h
```

**Research**

I searched around on the internet for people with a similar issue and came across the following relevant things:

- https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain/issues/105
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/806220/building-ucb-logo-6-errors-in-mathcalls-h
- [-isystem on a system include directory causes errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218953/isystem-on-a-system-include-directory-causes-errors)

The last of these is the most promising; it talks about why `-isystem` won't work here stating that the special `#include_next` traverses the include path in a different way. Here, the solution appears to be "don't use `-isystem` where you can help it", but since I've tried using `-I` only get get the same problem again, I'm not sure how I'd apply that here.

**Original issue**

When compiling with the new glibc, I get the following error (our build process ends up running some of the programs it compiles to generate further source to be compiled, hence this runtime error whilst compiling):

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: get-dynamic-info.h: 143: elf_get_dynamic_info: Assertion `info[DT_RPATH] == NULL' failed!
```

I found a couple of relevant things about this:

- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-get-local-gcc-to-link-with-local-glibc-404087/
- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/inconsistency-detected-by-ld-so-dynamic-link-h-62-elf_get_dynamic_info-assertion-621701/

The only solution I see there is completely recompiling gcc to use the new glibc. I'd like to avoid that if possible, which is what lead me down the include route.

**Eliminating the complex build system**

To try and eliminate the complex build system on the "real" project, I reproduced the problem using the following `test.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include <cmath>

int main() {

}
```

Compiled using:

```
> /path/to/gcc-6.3.0/bin/g++ test.cpp -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -Wl,--rpath=/path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/lib
```

Running yields the same original issue:

```
> ./a.out 
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: get-dynamic-info.h: 143: elf_get_dynamic_info: Assertion `info[DT_RPATH] == NULL' failed!
```

Trying to use the newer headers yields the same include issue:

```
> /path/to/gcc-6.3.0/bin/g++ test.cpp -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -Wl,--rpath=/path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/lib -isystem /path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/include
In file included from /usr/include/math.h:71:0,
                 from /path/to/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/cmath:45,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/include/bits/mathcalls.h:63:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 __MATHCALL_VEC (cos,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
```

**TL;DR**

How can I get g++ to include the headers from my glibc build correctly, without it accidentally including incompatible files from /usr/include?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ? And of [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) ? GCC being free software, you can recompile it and improve it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch some parts that looked relevant, but not all. There's a lot to go through! Specifically I took a look at the FAQ and grepped the complete PDF manual for glibc and headers, which is what lead me to isystem. I also took a look here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Installation

Modifying gcc and/or rebuilding it is a last resort, I'm hoping to avoid it if possible as it would add even more "specialness" to our build process.

Comment: You probably have to look inside the documentation of [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) since it is (or may be) invoked by `gcc` or `g++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your GCC version,`<cmath>` uses `#include_next`, which means that you need to make sure that the directory which contains the `cmath` file comes *before* (on the include search path) the directory with the proper `math.h` for the version of glibc you are building against.

You can use `g++ -v` to view the search path. In your case, it probably looks like this:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 /project-foo/include
 /project-bar/include
 /path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/include
 /usr/include/c++/6
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

If you configure glibc with `--prefix=/usr` and install it with `DESTDIR=/path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install`, its header files will be installed into the directory `/path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/usr/include`. This means you should be able to use the `-isysroot` option, which rewrites the default `/usr/include` directory, resulting in the right ordering of the search path:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 /project-foo/include
 /project-bar/include
 /usr/include/c++/6
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6
 /usr/include/c++/6/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include-fixed
 /path/to/glibc-2.23/build/install/usr/include
```

Comment: I just tried this and it compiled, but when running I still get the `Assertion `info[DT_RPATH] == NULL'` problem. Since it answers the question, I'll still accept this, but if you have any other info regarding the assertion problem in an off-comment, that would be appreciated. If it's too complex an answer, then I'll just need to post a new question. The most obvious thing of using --sysroot instead created new problems that should go in their own question. Thank you!

Comment: You likely built glibc with `-Wl,--rpath`, that doesn't work.

Comment: Indeed I did, tried removing it, still no joy. I will ask another question :)