# Ignoring Werror for one specific file

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

error #1696: Implicit pointer conversion changes byteorder of the pointed-to types from "bigendian int" to "int"
  `if((processid = forkpty{{int*)&(execData->mFd)`

I have multiple files being compiled by a single makefile. One of those files say `xyz.c`is giving me byte-order error I tried to resolve such errors using this https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/628915

But this one is sticky. No matter what I do it didn't go away.

Attempts Made:

1) Went through https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/628915 but nothing helped.
2)if I take this file say `xyz.c` out of the makefile and comment it then it gives me undefined reference to lots of  functions which are used elsewhere. So this is obviously not a solution.

**Need is to ignore this warning so I 
Wonder if there is a way to make-Wnoerror for a particular file being compiled inside a Makefile.**

Comment: Have you seen the answer _[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6321839/645128)_ ?...  (_[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6321926/645128)_ in particular I think addresses your question best)

Comment: Note that the code (`if((processid = forkpty{{int*)&(execData->mFd)`) doesn't compile whether you ignore `-Werror` or not; it is invalid because of the `{` open braces at the start of what's meant to be a function call and cast, and the three missing `)` close brackets (parentheses).  That's 3 assuming the `{` are changed to `(`.

Comment: @ryyker You got me, bro! Thanks..

Comment: @ryyker but what exactly this isystem is doing instead of using I here?

Comment: _[Here is another answer discussing same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3371528/645128)_.  You just have to read the documentation at this point, then experiment.  Google GCC compiler (or linker) options.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible options,

1. Create a rule for the specific file in the Makefile, and don't pass `-Werror` when compiling it.
2. Use what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26003732/1983495).

   ```
   #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-W(your specific warning)"
   ```

   you can re-enable the warning later if you like.

Comment: `#pragma GCC diagnostic push` and `#pragma GCC diagnostic pop` can be useful to localize the changes wrought by `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwhatever"`.

Comment: Hi @Ihrob Al Asimi , it says unrecognized pragma for the second soln,