# Use -I instead of -isystem when using CMake find_package in compile_commands.json

Tags: cmake, cppcheck

My question is basically the inverse of this SO question - [Use -isystem instead of -I with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371127/use-isystem-instead-of-i-with-cmake)

I have a library I'm testing and the test application brings in the library via CMake's `find_package`

```
# CMakeLists.txt

...
find_package(as REQUIRED)
add_executable(as-tests tests.cpp ...)
target_link_libraries(as-tests as::as)
...
```

This all works fine but the problem is CMake seems to add `-isystem` to all include paths brought in this way as opposed to with `target_include_directories`. This is what I see when I generate a `compile_commands.json` file.

```
# compile_commands.json

...
{
  "directory": ...
  "command": ... -isystem <full/path/to/as/include/>" ...
  "file": ...
},
...
```

I was wondering if it's possible to pass a flag or setting to `find_package` to let CMake know this is not a `system` library but a `local` one (especially if I've installed it to somewhere that's not the default install location using `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` and later `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

The reason this is causing me pain is I'd like to use `cppcheck` to analyze these files but it (sensibly) ignores all files it deems to be `system` includes.

```
$ cppcheck --project=compile_commands.json --language=c++ --std=c++17 --enable=all

# will not analyse any includes with -isystem prefix
```

So in summary, can I do something like `find_package(as REQUIRED NOT_SYSTEM)` to get the normal `-I` to appear in `compile_commands.json`?

Thanks! :)

---

Update:

@mathstuf is 100% correct (thank you for your answer!) I wanted to expand on this slightly as the current state of things isn't exactly what I was after...

It is possible to set `NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED` on the target you are building, but not on imported targets..

e.g. You can do this:

```
project(app LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
set_target_properties(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED true)
```

but you cannot do this:

```
find_package(lib REQUIRED)
set_target_properties(
    lib::lib PROPERTIES
    NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED true)
```

This is alright, but this means if you have multiple imported targets you can't pick one particular library to be `-I` and another to remain as `-isystem` (`-isystem` is the default for all imported targets).

You can see more info about this here https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17348 and here https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17364

I guess I'll just have to live with everything being `-I` for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the target property [`NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED.html) you can set on the consuming target to remove that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.25, you have a new target property [SYSTEM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SYSTEM.html#prop_tgt:SYSTEM) that manages this behavior in the imported target, contrary to [NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED.html) property, which controls this in the *consuming* library.

So in your example, the correct syntax would be:

```
find_package(lib REQUIRED)
set_target_properties(
    lib::lib PROPERTIES
    SYSTEM false)
```